# get rid of video button on ios uiwebview

Tags: ios, video, button, uiwebview, playback

Is there some way to get rid of the giant uiwebview video play button whenever it detects a video. I just want to show a screen of a video without the play button in the way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you use the HTML5 video tag then appearance of controls is specified as an attibute i.e.

no controls

```
<video  src="sample_mpeg4.mp4"></video>
```

all controls

```
<video  src="sample_mpeg4.mp4" controls></video>
```

just one control

```
<video  src="sample_mpeg4.mp4" controls="Volume"></video>
```

P.S.
If you want the video to play inline within the UIWebView there are things you need to do within the HTML itself and also within the UIWebView implementation, I can add this info if required.